# Multithreaded/multiprocessing alternative to sco.optimize.minimize_scalar?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, mathematical-optimization, scipy-optimize

When using [`optimize.minimize_scalar()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar.html#scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar) of [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/index.html), I realize that it is just using one core of my computer.

Is there any possibility / alternative to run it on all cores of my CPU in parallel?

Comment: This uses a sequential algorithm. You may try to parallelize your function evaluation (often not worthwhile).